# After 10-20 minutes of gaming, my screen has black stripes on it, and has moved a bit to the left

Tags: display, hardware-failure, gaming

The problem began when I re-installed Windows 7 64-bit. The reason why I re-installed it, was because my computer was too slow on start-up, and had many viruses, so I wanted my computer to be clean. Now, when I am trying to play games such as Assassins Creed and Portal 2, my screen looks very weird (see pictures). And even when I shut the game down, my screen is just the same as in the game. It seems like my screen has moved to the left, and the left part of the screen is now on the right part of the screen. I don't know if there's a solution for this problem, but I hope someone can help me.

Pictures:

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Specs:

- Windows 7 x64
- Motherboard: ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3
- Processor: AMD FX-8210 Eight-Core Processor
- RAM: 16GB RAM
- Video card: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
- Temperature of video card when idle: 38°C

Comment: Overheating comes to mind.

Comment: My temperature is 54°C when this is happening, so I think it hasn't anything to do with overheating.

Comment: what monitor are you using? and what are you output settings to that monitor (resolution)? try other game screen resolutions or do not run it in full screen. When you leave the game, does not resolution pop back to originaal desktop resolutions? Change it manually, then you will not have to reboot to fix it.

Comment: I'm using the Dell 1708FP. Even when I'm not playing in fullscreen, this will happen.

Answer (score 2):

I am making the following assumptions based on what you said.  1.  Everything with your screen was okay previously and the problem only occurred after you reloaded Windows.  2.  When you boot it appears okay, but when you go into a game it goes bad and then when you exit the game it appears bad.  3.  A reboot of the computer fixes it.

If all of these are true, then go into your computer manufacturer's website and try and download a new copy of the video graphics driver and install it.  That or go to AMD and get their newest driver package and install it and try again.  Also try and do the same for your monitor.  It looks as though the resolution isn't working correctly on your video card/monitor combination.